# Cambiar IDIOMA de TECLADO en android studio

Tags: java, android

Estimados actualmente me encuentro con algunos problemas a la hora de algunas clases que varia segun el teclado que tenga seteado el telefono , existe alguna forma de atravez del SDK de android studio cambiar el teclado predeterminado del telefono , almenos mientras este en uso la aplicacion o solo para la aplicacion , desde ya gracias

Comment: Que quieres usar solo número o qué cosa ?

Comment: Quisiera que mi aplicacion utilize IDIOMA de espa;ol(Estado Unidos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Para cambiar idioma :**

```
Locale localizacion = new Locale("es", "ES");

Locale.setDefault(localizacion);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = localizacion;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

*Si necesitas mas información mira este [articulo](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) de la pagina de desarrollo de Android Studio.*

Comment: muchas gracias lo bichare!

Comment: De nada, me alegro haberte ayudado, saludos.